# How to edit hide column on floating menu - Aggrid

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I'm trying to edit the floating menu on the `ag-Grid` table because if I filter it and hide all columns, I can't click the button again to make them show up.

I tried some suppress configurations but I did not found yet exactly what I need

This is my table and it's columns

```
columnDefs = [
{headerName: 'test1', field: 'test1' },
{headerName: 'test2', field: 'test2', filter: false },
{headerName: 'test3', field: 'test3', filter: false }];

rowData = [];

<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [enableSorting]="false"
  [enableColResize]="true"
  [enableFilter]="true"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

https://prnt.sc/pubq1b

And that is what happen when I hide all columns

https://prnt.sc/pubqnu

All the buttons disappear and I can't make the columns show again

Could someone please send some tips about it, or if there is any `ag-Grid` configuration to change it. I was trying to don't allow hide them all, leave at least one or event to remove that filter possibility.

Thank you

Comment: Can u  show your code? Or upload it  on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: @ErikHer just added the code here.